# How to change my LinkedList Searching Node code with C

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I got some problem about searching specific Nodes in LinkedList.

Teacher taught me how to do it, But when I arrived at home, I forgot something that a few lines to be changed.

Below code is my homework made by myself.
I think main problems are

**listNode* searchNode here**

**temp = DL->head;**

or

**searchNode(m, o) ? printf("yes") : printf("no");** here.

My SearchNode code always answer just "No".

How do I solve it?

sorry for bad English. :(

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>  


typedef struct ListNode {
    int data;
    struct ListNode* link;
}listNode;

typedef struct {
    listNode* head;
} linkedList_h;

listNode* searchNode(linkedList_h* DL, int x) {
    listNode* temp;
    temp = DL->head;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        if (temp->data, x == 0) {
            return temp;
        }
        else {
            temp = temp->link;
        }
    }
    return temp;
}

void insertFirstListNode(linkedList_h* num, int data) {
    listNode* newNode = (listNode*)malloc(sizeof(listNode));
    newNode->link = num->head;
    newNode->data = data;
    num->head = newNode;
}

void insertLastNode(linkedList_h* num, int data) {
    listNode* newNode;
    listNode* temp;
    newNode = (listNode*)malloc(sizeof(listNode));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->link = NULL;
    if (newNode->link == NULL) {                            
        num->head = newNode;        
        return;
    }

    temp = num->head;
    while (temp->link != NULL) temp = temp->link;   
    temp->link = newNode;                            
}


linkedList_h* createLinkedList_h() {
    linkedList_h* Newlist = (linkedList_h*)malloc(sizeof(linkedList_h));
    Newlist->head = NULL;
    return Newlist;
}



void printList(linkedList_h* L) {
    listNode* p;
    printf("L = (");
    p = L->head;
    while (p != NULL) {
        printf("%d", p->data);
        p = p->link;
        if (p != NULL) printf(", ");
    }
    printf(") \n");
}


int main() {
    int i, j = 0;
    int k;
    int o = 0;

    linkedList_h* m;
    m = createLinkedList_h();
    insertLastNode(m, 4);
    printList(m);
    printf("size input\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &i);
    printf("%d\n", i);
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        printf("input \n");
        scanf_s("%d", &k);
        insertFirstListNode(m, k);
    }
    printList(m);
    printf("Find Nodes : ");
    scanf_s("%d", &o);
    printf("your Nodes : %d\n", o);
    searchNode(m, o) ? printf("yes") : printf("no");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: As a matter of style, you should probably check searchNode to see if it's null, not rely on zero equivalency.  `while(x)` is OK, but the C standard defines that 0 cast to the type void * is both a null pointer and a null pointer constant.  That's pretty far afield; use `searchNode != NULL` instead.  It makes things much clearer.

Comment: What is `if (temp->data, x == 0) ` supposed to do? Most likely you're missusing the comma operator here.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Now I see, that was my mistake. Professor taught me with "Char" but, homework was for the "Int"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `temp->data, x == 0` fetches the value of `temp->data` and throws it away, then does `x == 0` where the result will be used for the condition.

That means you will only return with a non-null node if the *searched for* value is `0`, the contents in the list is irrelevant (as it's not used in the comparison). And then it will always return the first node in the list.

This doesn't really make sense. It seems what you want is `temp->data == x`.

Comment: Oh, Got it, i'll go right now and try it again. ++++ Yeeeaaaaaah It works!!!! Thx!!!!